# doing bernoulli in r

Tags: r, bernoulli-distribution

The question might be too simple, but sometimes I see an extra "+1" in parameters passed to distributions,

For example for Bernoulli I  would do:

```
dbeta(seq, n*p, n*(1-p))
```

But in a tutorial I saw:

```
dbeta(seq,n*p+1,n*(1-p)+1)
```

Is this "+1" some sort of correction for when we have little data?

Comment: Please clarify the context: although you write "Bernoulli," your calculations concern Beta distributions.  Are you perhaps concerned about updating Beta priors for Bernoulli experiments?